# ¿Como extraer parte del código fuente de la web?

Tags: vba, macros, internet-explorer

Quisiera saber como puedo extarer el nombre de una imagen, les dejo el codigo html.

Necesito extraer este nombre.  images/capchs/4, es una pagina de prueba a fin de poder obtenr datos exactos de la web, para luego poder armar un archivo general de todos los datos conseguidos.

No tengo conocimiento de como poder extraer una linea exacta del codigo, lo que que conseguido es ingresar a la pagina, rellenar los datos de formulario,  vuelvo a la pregunta principal, necesito extraer la linea exacta del codigo que en este caso es la numero 77.

```html
<form name="mainf" onsubmit="javascript:dosub();return false;">
   <div align="center">
    <table>
     <tbody><tr>
      <td><div id="cimg1"><img width="35" height="55" src="images/capchs/4.png"></div></td>
      <td><div id="cimg2"><img width="35" height="55" src="images/capchs/2.png"></div></td>
      <td><div id="cimg3"><img width="35" height="55" src="images/capchs/4.png"></div></td>
      <td><div id="cimg4"> </div></td>
      <td><div id="cimg5"> </div></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody></table>
   </div>
   <div align="center">
    <input type="text" name="capcha65986933280" value="" style="width:200px;height:30px;font-size:15px;">
   </div>
   <div align="center">
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><input type="button" value="SEGUIR" style="width:200px;height:30px;font-size:15px;" onclick="javascript:dosub()"></font></font>
   </div>
   <div align="center"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
    Para obtener 10 centavos, ingrese los símbolos que se muestran en la imagen, haga clic en "Continuar" (o Intro) </font></font>
<font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
    Si puede reconocer símbolos, simplemente haga clic en "Continuar" o Intro
   </font></font></div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Esto se llama webscraping... intentaste algo?

Comment: No, no tengo idea de como se usa, hasta ahora consigo copiar el codigo en una celda excel, pero no se copia todo y tampoco la parte que necesito.